# Error in dimnames(m) <- list(Namesresp, Variables) : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r

Please explain the error (set out in the title) with this script:

```
Height <-c(156,610,154,148,170,178,188,163,165,157)
Weight <-c (48,56,45,50,68,75,81,65,70,49)

Mydata <-data.frame(Height, Weight)

Namesresp<-c ("Susan","Mary","Lily","Hillary","Mike","John",
              "William","Cathy","Wendy","Jeff")

variables<-c ("Height","Weight")

dimnames (Mydata)<-list(Namesresp,Variables)

Gender<-c("Female","Female","Female","Male","Male",
          "Male","Female","Female","Female","Male")

Mydata <-data.frame(Mydata,Gender)
Age <-sample(20:50, size=10, replace=T)
Mydata1 <-cbind(Mydata, Age)

m<-matrix(c(Height,Weight,Age),ncol=3)
dimnames(m) <-list(Namesresp,Variables)

objects ()
str ()
summary(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

One note: you use both `variables` and `Variables` in your script (lower-case vs. capital V); R is case-sensitive, so you'll need to pick one.

The error is that your matrix `m` has 3 columns, but you've only supplied it a vector of length two (`variables`) for the names. You'll need to supply a vector of length 3 to resolve that error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is associated with this line of code: `dimnames(m) <- list(Namesresp, variables)`

It occurs because you are trying to give names to the three columns of the matrix with a variable that has only 2 names.

There is a typo error with the object variables which defined as variables with a lower case v but in the code has a upper case V.

the matrix `m` looks like this:

```r
m <- matrix(c(Height, Weight, Age), ncol=3)

#>       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#>  [1,]  156   48   21
#>  [2,]  610   56   27
#>  [3,]  154   45   46
#>  [4,]  148   50   42
#>  [5,]  170   68   43
#>  [6,]  178   75   20
#>  [7,]  188   81   20
#>  [8,]  163   65   42
#>  [9,]  165   70   40
#> [10,]  157   49   50
```

Then you get the error:

```
dimnames(m) <- list(Namesresp, variables)
#> Error in dimnames(m) <- list(Namesresp, variables): length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

The code to give names to the matrix is fine for the rownames with `Namesresp` but `variables` is a vector with only two elements:

```
variables 
#> [1] "Height" "Weight"
```

If you edit the code you get:

```
dimnames(m) <- list(Namesresp, c(variables, "Age"))
m
#>         Height Weight Age
#> Susan      156     48  21
#> Mary       610     56  27
#> Lily       154     45  46
#> Hillary    148     50  42
#> Mike       170     68  43
#> John       178     75  20
#> William    188     81  20
#> Cathy      163     65  42
#> Wendy      165     70  40
#> Jeff       157     49  50
```

**data**

```
Height <-c(156,610,154,148,170,178,188,163,165,157)
Weight <-c (48,56,45,50,68,75,81,65,70,49)

Namesresp<-c ("Susan","Mary","Lily","Hillary","Mike","John",
              "William","Cathy","Wendy","Jeff")

variables <-c("Height","Weight")

Age <-sample(20:50, size=10, replace = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>